# Why buy ssl-endpoint heroku addon?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku

So i just joined a company that is changing DNS name. So, in order to redirect traffic from www.oldsite.com to newsite.com, i needed to do a redirection (301) on the DNS register. Of course, also removed oldsite.com from the heroku's app settings. For the bare oldsite.com, i needed to create a second rails app called oldsite-redirect so when https://oldsite.com is requested, it's redirected to https://newsite.com via javascript (window.location...).
I forgot to mention that somehow, all the http://oldsite.com requests were redirected in the browser to https://oldsite.com.
So on this second app, i loaded the oldsite's crts (otherwise https:// were raising a "domain doesn't match warning"), made the arrangements in DNS Config Panel, and now it's redirected without any problems. https://oldsite.com redirects to https://newsite.com and i didn't have to buy the SSL-Endpoint heroku's addon. So, why people buy it if you can serve https content without buying it?

Btw, i have been googling and yahooing and i haven't find such answer.

Also do you have any opinions/suggestion on my monkeypatch redirection?

Thanks in advance for your clarification.

Comment: You don't need to pay for the SSL endpoint add-on anymore: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl

Comment: Oh, thanks man! So right now SSL-Endpoint addon, doesn't have any advantage vs Heroku's right?

Comment: That add-on used to be the only way to get an SSL certificate on heroku. It has been replaced by SNI last may. It is now deprecated.